# Speed up a Update, Inner Join, where date between, group by MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Im running the below query and was wondering if there is anyway to speed up.

Im running the same query multiple times for each month and it's odd because some months run very quick (10 seconds) and some are taking a very long time (30 minutes). The difference in totals between months is not that much so im not sure what the problem is.

Here is the query

```
UPDATE appmonth a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT activity_id, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM appmaster 
    WHERE upload_date BETWEEN '2014/05/01' AND '2014/05/31'
    GROUP BY activity_id) b
  on b.activity_id = a.activity_id
SET `2014_05` = b.counts
```

I dont have any indexes on the table appmonth that is being updated.

I have the following indexes setup on the appmaster table

- activity, upload_date
- activity
- upload_date, activity

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this way:

```
UPDATE appmonth AS a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT activity_id, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM appmaster 
     WHERE upload_date >='2014/05/01' AND upload_date <= '2014/05/31'
     GROUP BY activity_id) AS b
  ON b.activity_id = a.activity_id
SET a.`2014_05` = b.counts
```

BETWEEN is a slow condition.

And add index 'activity_id' on appmonth.

P.S. the index 'activity_id' on appmaster is useless because you have yet 'activity_id, upload_date'